# Problems with htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a couple of directories  to always be https and everything else be http

With the exception of images, css files and js files which should be on whatever the page is on.

So I created this htaccess rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://server.com/$1 [R=301,L]




RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^login/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^login/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But when I go to /login I get an error

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

What needs to change for this to work properly?

Comment: Is `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` supported on your Apache?

Comment: Yes, its running on a AWS Load Balanced Beanstalk, so I have to use that method for comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` or `%{REQUEST_URI}` can't be used in the `RewriteRule`, only in the `RewriteCond`

You can use %1, %2 etc as a reference to the different matching parts of the condition tho. But the full Request URI can be solved by this in the rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule (.*) http://some_host$1`

So if the hostname is not dynamic, it's pretty easy to fix.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried that without much luck, however what I Can say is that I removed the last 3 lines and it worked for redirecting to https, but without those last 3 lines, it wont redirect the other way, so its seems the last 3 lines are causing some sort of issue.

Comment: Did you try `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https`?